# MySql: How to show all the tasks created by each users?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using accordion panel to show those users who have created some task. For example:

user 1 as Tim has created 3 tasks (task 1: pay bill, task 2: call Mark and task 3: clean car)

user 2 as Jim has created 2 tasks (task 1: cook food and task 2: Dentist Appointment at 3 pm)

I am able to display both the users Tim and Jim and when I click on the accordion panel for Tim or Jim, I get to see all the tasks created by these users.

I just wanted to show, when I click on Tim accordion panel, I only want to see the task created by Tim only and not Jim and same thing with Jim, when I clicked on Jim accordion panel, I want only Jim's task to display and not Tim in the panel.

```
Select users.id  as 'userID', users.name, tasks.id, tasks.task,
tasks.iscompleted, tasks.createdBy, tasks.completedBy, tasks.status
FROM users
Left Join tasks on  tasks.createdBy = users.id
where tasks.iscompleted = false AND tasks.createdBy = users.id
group by users.id
ORDER by tasks.id DESC
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is wrong with your query result?

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN y... WHERE y=` is equivalent to `INNER JOIN y` - and a GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions is never a good thing. For further help, maybe see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Just change this part with user id you need to filter: `where tasks.iscompleted = false AND users.id = JIM_USER_ID` where `JIM_USER_ID` is user id you want to filter (1,2,3 or whatever it is)

Comment: and I feel like you don't need `GROUP BY` part at all

Comment: @Alex I tried this option but its not working.